# what are the top 10 library in python to learn as a beginner?

Tags: python

what  are the top 10 library in python to learn as a beginner?
I just finish to learn the basic of python and I want to move on the something more advance so I need some library to start learn as a beginner in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what direction you want to go in. Some libraries are important across a variety of fields, such `os`, `re` (for regular expressions), `sys` and `math`. `numpy` is also an important library to master.  Then, for data analysis, you have various libraries that are crucial such as `pandas`, `matplotlib`, `seaborn`. For web development, there are `django` and `flask.` For machine learning, there are many, many libraries, such as `sklearn.`

I don't think there are some specific libraries for 'beginners,' you'll have to use libraries as per the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the field you intend to go into, e.g.

1. For Web development: Django, Flask ...
2. For Data Analysis: matplotlib, numpy, pandas ...
3. Machine Learning: Keras, Theanos, TensorFlow ...
4. GUI Development: tkinter, kivy, pyqt ...

or any other field you may be interested in, the list is inexhaustible, but I'm making these suggestions.